# Firebase Notifications are failing to iOS platform after App Transfer

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, testflight, app-transfer

Recently we made our app transfer to new account. From then on I see fcm notifications are not getting triggered to app (dev/testflight). 
*Created a new APNS Auth key and uploaded to FCM console.

Note: After the app transfer I am checking in dev mode and Testflight mode. There is no recent production build after the app transfer.

Still live app is receiving notifications.

Any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try these things

1)Whenever you are stuck with notification issues try sending a push via the GUI console that firebase provide to send notifications

2) If your live app at Appstore is not receiving push notification but is receiving notification only when running via Xcode then you have not uploaded the production certificate to firebase console

3)If you have uploaded both production and development certificates and still notifications are not received then download the latest certificates and upload them again to the firebase console

Comment: Thanks for suggestions @harshal jadhav

*I already tried from firebase console, status of notifications is Failed
*Live app in appStore is receiving notifications. After appTransfer I created a new APNS AUTH key. Now I trying to check in dev mode here I am not receiving any notifications
*I am not using certificates, rather I am using APNS Auth key