# InvalidParameters: AppleDeliveryError:BAD_REQUEST_TOPIC_DISALLOWED

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

After transferring the app, push messages show the error(InvalidParameters: AppleDeliveryError:BAD_REQUEST_TOPIC_DISALLOWED) and do not come intermittently.
We currently use FCM. Neither the .p8 file nor the push key made any changes. If this problem is with the .p8 file or Pushkey, it is strange that the message comes intermittently.

App transfer has been restored. But the issue wasn't resolved.

What is the problem?

Comment: I think it is quite understandable. If you transferred your app to another account, the `TeamID` also changed, and your `KeyID` will not be usable.

Comment: But then shouldn't the message come at all?

Comment: It would help if you created another APNs Key on the new developer account to make it work after the transfer is completed.

Comment: In that case, app distribution should proceed, right?

Comment: You don't have to upload another binary. Just need to create a new key, and then make an integration on the BE side/FCM.

Comment: Oh, I understand. But why is the message being sent like that intermittently?

Comment: I think it's an FCM exception, have no idea about their implementation.

Comment: First, I canceled the transfer and applied the previous keyID and teamID.
I think it's probably an FCM issue, so I'll look into it further and proceed with the transfer.

Comment: There is an existing issue like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298994